# How can I set a system variable in NetBeans, System.getenv()?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a standalone Java program with the following command :

```
String p2 = System.getenv("USERPARAMETER");
```

How I can set this system variable in NetBeans 8.0 as if
`USERPARAMETER` variable was coming from command line?

Comment: do you mean set the variable p2 to some command line arg, or do you mean set some actual system variable on the OS level?

Answer (score 0):

This system variable is coming from command line.
I have a windows machine and the command would be

set USERPARAMETER = name

I know that in Eclipse it is possible with "Run configurations"
command to set system variable inside Eclipse.

After that you can debug the program with Eclipse as if 
USERPARAMETER was coming from command line.

I think in Netbeans this should be also possible but I dont know how ?